# owl carousel with javascript does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, owl-carousel

can you tell me what the problem is that it does not work properly? it is a owl carousel with five image and i add some javascript code but it is not working as well. i add owl.carousel.min.js
and jquery library but raly i dont know what the problem is.

https://codepen.io/lena-bt/pen/NWdwbrQ

```
<div class="sliders owl-carousel">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="img"><img src="https://www.itaf.eu/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/best-laptops-cover.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="title">briana tazor</div>
      <div class="sub-title">graphic designer</div>
      <div class="btn">
        <button>read more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="img"><img src="https://www.itaf.eu/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/best-laptops-cover.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="title">briana tazor</div>
      <div class="sub-title">graphic designer</div>
      <div class="btn">
        <button>read more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="img"><img src="https://www.itaf.eu/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/best-laptops-cover.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="title">briana tazor</div>
      <div class="sub-title">graphic designer</div>
      
      <div class="btn">
        <button>read more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="img"><img src="https://www.itaf.eu/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/best-laptops-cover.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="title">briana tazor</div>
      <div class="sub-title">graphic designer</div>
      
      <div class="btn">
        <button>read more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="img"><img src="https://www.itaf.eu/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/best-laptops-cover.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="title">briana tazor</div>
      <div class="sub-title">graphic designer</div>
      
      <div class="btn">
        <button>read more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and it is my javascript code

```
<script>
  $(".sliders").owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 2000,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The error is that you are loading the Owl carousel scripts before your JS and possibly jquery. In your Codepen, move the Owl carousel JS from the top to the bottom after all of your other scripts.

Comment: You're also adding jQuery and Owl Carousel a bunch of times. The only scripts that you need before you closing body tag are `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>` That's it. You can remove everything else.

Comment: I changed it but it didn't work

Comment: It looks like you changed a couple things and the old pen isn't visible. Here is the working example moving the JS before the closing `<body>` tag. https://codepen.io/chrislafrombois/pen/YzNYKdR